# Julia Reverse N-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, julia

In Python, Numpy arrays can be reversed using the standard `[::-1]` i.e.

```
A = np.diag(np.arange(1,3)) 
A[::, ::-1] 
A[::-1] 
A[::-1, ::-1]
```

Julia does not support `[::-1]` and the `reverse` method only works on 1D arrays and only 1D columns (where as rows are 2D by default).

Is there an alternative I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried [end:-1:1] in place of [::-1]?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following, which is essentially the same as the `numpy` version:

```
julia> X = rand(3,3)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.782622  0.996359  0.335781
 0.719058  0.188848  0.985693
 0.455355  0.910717  0.870187

julia> X[end:-1:1,end:-1:1]
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.870187  0.910717  0.455355
 0.985693  0.188848  0.719058
 0.335781  0.996359  0.782622
```

Comment: yes, I just saw specerlyon2's comment and it worked, I guess it's a natural thing for matlab users? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @user3467349 That's indeed the idiomatic way to do it in MATLAB, too.

Comment: Its almost exactly what the numpy code does, except the `end`  and `1` is implicit, so seems more natural regardless of other language experience.

Comment: In case you're using arrays whose indices aren't `1:length(arr)`, you should use `X[end:-1:begin]`

Answer (score 7):

In [Julia 1.0](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/base/arrays/#Base.reverse-Tuple%7BAbstractArray%7BT,1%7D%20where%20T%7D), to reverse a (column) vector:

```
julia> reverse([1, 2, 3])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 2
 1
```

For reversing rows, just state that you want to flip the second dimension:

```
julia> reverse([1 2 3], dims=2)
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  2  1
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you can also index in reverse using `end:-1:1`, and that way also allows you to request a view instead of a copy:

```
julia> a = reshape(randperm(9), 3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  7  9
 5  2  1
 3  6  8

julia> @view a[:, end:-1:1]
3×3 view(::Matrix{Int64}, :, 3:-1:1) with eltype Int64:
 9  7  4
 1  2  5
 8  6  3
```

Comment: Note that this creates a copy, not a view of the original

Comment: Example for creating a view now added.

Answer (score 4):

Following up @IainDunning's answer, an important difference between numpy and Julia here is that `X[:,end:-1:1]` in Julia returns a copy and in numpy `X[:,::-1]` will return a view of the same data (no copy is made).

I'm just learning Julia myself, but it seems like you can accomplish something similar in Julia using `sub(X, :, size(X)[2]:-1:1)`, which returns Julia's equivalent of a view (`SubArray`). Interestingly, you can't use the `end` keyword in this construct as far as I can see, and instead you must pass in the actual end index in the dimension.

Comment: note that `sub` from Julia v0.4 is now `view` in Julia v0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `flipdim(mat, d)`.

Ref: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/

Answer (score 0):

Try this set of functions:

```
function reverser(x::AbstractArray, dims::AbstractVector{<:Integer})
    y = copy(x)
    for d in dims
        y = reverse(y, dims=d)
    end
    return y
end

reverser(x::AbstractArray) = reverser(x, 1:ndims(x)) # all dimensions
reverser(x::AbstractArray, d::Integer) = reverser(x, [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Julia 1.6 supports reversing any or all of the dimensions of an arbitrary multidimensional array ([implemented here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/37367)).  To reverse all of the dimensions, you can simply do `reverse(X)`.